# Is there a way to change volume of a single process?

Tags: audio

In other words, does something like the volume mixer in windows, where you can change the volume of different applications, exist? Also if there is, please help me understand how it works.

Answer (score 6):

That's a very general question.

"Volume" is not a characteristic of a process (in fact, nothing audio related is).

The audio infrastructure for Linux (I assume you mean Linux, you didn't say in your question) has grown historically, and is not easy to explain in a single answer.

However, if your distro runs Pulseaudio (most distros do today), you can use `pavucontrol` to adjust the volume of audio streams. Very often, an application has a single audio stream.

So this should likely do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the distro you are it is already possible, if it is using pulseaudio, try running the program:

```
pavucontrol
```

[image: pavucontrol]

Answer (score 1):

KDE's system settings allow you to do that:
[image]